# Вопрос по pdfmake. Как отобразить картинку в таблице с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, pdf

Дайте, пожалуйста, пример кода, для отображения картинки в `PDF`-файле, созданном с помощью библиотеки `pdfmake`.

На входе имеется ссылка на картинку формата `PNG` и `JS` язык.
Необходимо сделать без вмешательства сервера.

```
table:{
            margin:[50,50,50,50],
            widths:[110,110,110,110],
            body:massiveOfOpersRouting,
            headerRows:1
        }
```

Comment: Ivan Zagorskiy, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотрите video-урок по использованию `Pdfmake` на русском языке:
   [Pdfmake - простое создание PDF документов используя JavaScript](https://youtu.be/K4RxSioS6Dw).
2. Пример кода для отображения картинки в `PDF`-файле вы найдёте на [странице Pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted). Ищите там «Images».